# nested PLSQL in a tabular form

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to achieve the following result (the first line is header)

```
Level 1    | Level 2     |  Level 3 |   Level 4   | Person
Technicals | Development | Software | Team leader | Eric
Technicals | Development | Software | Team leader | Steven
Technicals | Development | Software | Team leader | Jana
```

How can I do so? I tried to use the following code. The first part is to create the hierarchy which works fine. The second part is to have the date in the above mentioned table is a pretty  painful.

```
SELECT * FROM (  /* level2 */ 
   SELECT * FROM (  /* level1 */
          SELECT * FROM arc.localnode   /*create hierarchy */
                 WHERE tree_id = 2408362  
                 CONNECT BY PRIOR node_id = parent_id
                 START WITH parent_id IS NULL ) l1node
          LEFT JOIN names on l1node.prent_id  = names.name_id ) l2node
```

At this point, I am quite lost. A bit of guidance and suggestion would be a lot of help :-)

There are two tables. The first table has data like this:

```
NODE_ID | PREV_ID  | NEXT_ID |  PARENT_ID 
1421864             3482917 1421768         
3482981 3482917     1421866 1421768     
3482911 3060402     3482913 1421768         
3482917 1421864     3482981 1421768
```

This is a complicated because it is in hieraracy. So obviously a PARENT_ID can be the NODE_ID of some other PARENT_ID. Similarly the parent_ID can be the PREV_ID and NEXT_ID.

The names are in seperate table with name_id. The name ID in this table is similar to NODE_ID of the main table in hieraracy.

Comment: What does your table structure and data look like? That would help in developing the necessary query.

Comment: Better, but still not entirely clear. Have you looked at `CONNECT_BY_ROOT`? I think that may be the piece you're looking for.

Comment: I guess that CONNECT_BY_ROOT works if you are dealing with one table only. Here I have two table which makes things a bit tricky

Comment: How about you show a complete example? Give the data from both tables and the expected result. Explain what you've tried, where you're stuck, and what you're missing.

Comment: I have uploaded the files here:

 www.thebombercommand.info/misc/names.sql (the name table)
 www.thebombercommand.info/misc/codes.sql (the code table)

 They have data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Stragg Package mentioned in AskTom in the below link

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402

Your can also refer the below link in oracle forum

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2258996

Kindly post create and insert statements for your requirement so that we can test it and confirm